# How to overwrite a folder in a git repo using merge?

Tags: git

I have a branch `refactor` that I want to merge into `main`.
We have rewritten large parts of our frontend codebase in the `refactor` branch so a regular merge is just going to be a mess and gives quite a few errors etc.

This is the file structure:
`refactor`

- Repo

  - Frontend *Lots of changes
  - Backend

`main`

- Repo

  - Frontend
  - Backend  *Some changes

Only the frontend part has changed in the refactor branch so I basically want to overwrite that part in main. But main has some changes in backend so I don't want to overwrite those changes.

How can I merge these branches the way I want without doing it manually and loosing history?

Comment: You may have success with a `cherry-pick`. The SHA parameter can be multiple, denoted by `..`: `5hA1ABCD..F00DBAAD` where the first SHA is a common ancestor.

Comment: Why merge will be a mess ? If you have conflict this is because your change things in both branches

Comment: `git checkout --theirs backend/` can help to easily fix conflict

Comment: If the *some changes* do not conflict with your *lots of changes*, the merge should not give you a mess at all at the textual level. Of course, there may be semantic conflicts that are not captured by a merge, but there is no automated method that could help you with that. Why don't you just try the merge in a temporary clone?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We found a way by using `git checkout HEAD -- .` after pulling main into the refactor branch. Then we had to delete some files and fix some minor issues

Comment: @Ôrel the "mess" was that git had duplicated some changes here and there without including them in merges. This ment we would have to actually go through every file after merging to remove the mess afterwards. We'd rather avoid doing all that manual work. Very prone to errors